# add number values from select option to current value in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find a way to add the selected option value which are only numbers to the current value in a mysql database.

my html code is like this:

```
<select name="ratingstars">
    <option>Select one option</option>
    <option value="1">Very poor</option>
    <option value="2">Bad</option>
    <option value="3">Not too bad</option>
    <option value="4">Good</option>
    <option value="5">Very good</option>
    </select>
```

my php is like this:

```
$ratingstars = $_POST['ratingstars'];

      if ($stmt = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE registration SET total_value = ?  WHERE id = ?")){
                $stmt->bind_param('si', $ratingstars, $rated);  

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

        }
```

usual way is like this:

```
total_value = total_value + 1
```

but what do i need to do in my example shown above?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ratingstars = $_POST['ratingstars'];

if ($stmt = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE registration SET total_value = total_value + ?  WHERE id = ?")) 
{
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $ratingstars, $rated);  

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

}
```

You can just add the new amount to the old amount in the sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db_conx->prepare("UPDATE registration SET total_value = total_value + ?  WHERE id = ?")
->bind('si',$ratingstars, $id);
```